# Why TLS protocol sends the MAC address together with the messages' hash?

Tags: ssl, encryption

I saw on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#SSL_3.0), on section **"Client-authenticated TLS handshake**", that on the end of the TLS handshake the client send an encrypted  **Finish** message, containing a hash and MAC over the previous handshake messages.

I understand why this message is required. Both the client and the server need to verify that the handshake is complete and all the data from now on will be decrypted successfully on the other side.

But, why the protocol use the MAC address for verification? The server can't verify that this is the real MAC address of the client so what's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't. It sends a Message Authentication Code.

Comment: MAC here stands for Message Authentication Code. Not MAC address. It's a cryptography thing, probably explained in Wikipedia.

Comment: Oh! that's make more sense.. Thank you!